# List и Allocator [std::initializer_list]

Tags: c++, list, конструктор

Есть проблемы со следующими конструкторами

```
List(const List& ls)
    : List(std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::select_on_container_copy_construction(ls.get_allocator())) {

    genList(ls.sz);

    for (Node* cur = root->right, *curLs = ls.root->right;
        cur != root; cur = cur->right, curLs = curLs->right) {

        NodeAllocTraits::construct(allocN, cur, curLs->value, cur->left, cur->right);
    }
}

List(std::initializer_list<int> c, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator())  : allocN(alloc) {

        genList(c.size());

        for (Node* it = root->right; it != root; it = it->right) {
            NodeAllocTraits::construct(allocN, it, it->left, it->right);
        }
}
```

Для проверки работы конструкторов есть следующий тест

```
TEST_CASE("List(const List& other)", "[List: Construct]") {
  SetupTest();
  const size_t size = 5;
  List<TypeWithCounts, AllocatorWithCount<TypeWithCounts>> l1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
  List<TypeWithCounts, AllocatorWithCount<TypeWithCounts>> l2(l1);

  REQUIRE(l2.size() == size);
  REQUIRE(MemoryManager::allocator_allocated != 0);
  REQUIRE(MemoryManager::allocator_constructed == size * 2);
  REQUIRE(AreListsEqual(l1, l2));
  for (auto& value : l1) {
    REQUIRE(*value.copy_c == 2); // тест не проходит,получается 1 == 2
  }
}
```

Как создать копии элементов при вызове конструктора List(const List& other)?

Comment: @CrazyElf это C++

Comment: Но сам вопрос всё же нужно перевести на русский - таковы правила. Либо задавайте в таком виде на английской части СО